# Putting a header view above a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to implement a header/list combination similar to what you see in the Instagram profile screen, where the header scrolls away and you scroll through the user's posts.

You can't use a scroll view that contains everything since that would mean having to load all the list items up front. And if you use the RecyclerView the scrollbar is in the RecyclerView and doesn't scroll the header away.

I suppose the header can be made into rows in the RecyclerView, but that seems kind of hacky. Is there a better way I'm not seeing?

Comment: Well, if not wrapping in `ScrollView` implementing a `RecyclerViewAdapter` with headerview at position 0 is your only option.

Comment: Shame we still have no better answer for this common problem.  Placing the header inside RecyclerView has lots of issues if the header has any views like EditText or anything beyond simple TextView or buttons... anything that has issues with being "recycled" as you scroll.  There is no need for the header to be recycled in most cases, so it just adds a lot of hacks that otherwise wouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these scroll tricks using the new `Toolbar` class in Lollipop: [scrolltricks](https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/scrolltricks)

He implements the exact functionality Instagram has. The ActionBar scrolls away upon scrolling down.